# Android app is native or JavaVM code?

Tags: android, compilation

Probably an stup!@# question.

I dont know nothing about developing apps for Android, but I was wondering if the applications for Android, when they are compiled, the code generated is PURE ANDROID NATIVE CODE, or is Java Virtual Machine compatible code.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most apps for Android are Java apps. They are compiled to .class files by the Java compiler, then the dx compiler takes the .class and compiles them to .dex files, which are executable by the Dalvik VM on Android (which is the Java VM).

Although the Dalvik VM is made to run Java code, it is significantly different than the standard Java VM on your computer. The standard VM is a "stack based" machine, whereas the Dalvik VM is "register based".

You can also make apps with the NDK, and write them in C or C++. This is not Java compatible in any way (although you can interface the native C code with the Java code with JNI).

Answer (score 4):

It has its own virtual machine, [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways to do it:

1. All Java
2. All Native
3. Half Java, half native.  Android libraries can be written in C and compiled into native code, then called from Java.  Your application could be a mix of both, if you wish.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#Native_development_kit